# No assignment of copy by value in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, clang

Can someone explain to me why the following does not work (`test` is `const` inside of `blub`). Since `test` is copied by value I was assuming, I could set it since it is functor local.

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<bool> test;
    auto blub = [test]() {
        test = std::make_shared<bool>(false);
    };

    return 0;
}
```

To make this working, first I have to introduce a new `shared_ptr`, assign `test` and then I can normally assign the other `shared_ptr`.
BTW: I am using clang 3.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the `operator()` of lambdas is `const` by default. You need to use the `mutable` keyword to make it non-const:

```
auto blub = [test]() mutable {
    test = std::make_shared<bool>(false);
};
```

Comment: So by `const` you mean all captured values are const - or only the copy by value?

Comment: Just like with a hand-written function object, only those captured by value. The captures are members of the lambda and the operator is declared as `Result operator()() const;`